# python pip cryptography build wheel fail

Tags: python, ubuntu, cryptography, pip, quandl

I am trying to install python packages like quandl. Since I am using pip3 I am installing the package using the following command in ubuntu 16.

```
sudo pip3 install quandl
```

This gives me the following error.

```
Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
```

I have installed wheel and cryptography as well. But it would not work. Could some one help me with this?

Answer (score 10):

Cleared the error. I installed the Openssl. I upgraded cryptography.

Install Open-ssl using the following command for Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: I had the same error when trying to update the cryptography package via pip3, and fixed it with the solution you provided.